# multiple MySQL instance on FreeBSD

Tags: mysql, instance, freebsd, bsd

Dear all Professionals

We have a serious problem to create Mysql Instance on FreeBSD os.
Here is my progress to make an instance:

1- Create new database instance on new destination

```
mkdir /mysql2/mysql
mkdir /mysql2/mysql/data
mkdir /mysql2/mysql/log
mkdir /mysql2/mysql/run
mkdir /mysql2/mysql/lock
chown -R mysql:mysql /mysql2/mysql
/usr/local/libexec/mysqld --initialize --datadir= /mysql2/mysql/data --user= mysql2
```

but in the beginning of this progress, i have an error and I cloud not figure out how to solve it:

```
[Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 28782 (request: 263271)
[Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 14310 (requested 131555)
[Warning] Ignoring user change to '' because the user was set to 'mysql' earlier on the command line

[ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
[ERROR] Aborting
```

FreeBSD 10.3
Mysql57-server-5.7.20_1

We were wondering if anybody could help us to handle this problem

Comment: You have a space between the `=` and the value of the parameter, which may be illegal. Also, you set the user name to `mysql2`, which is inconsistent with the preceding statement.

Answer (score 0):

One way to have multiple instances of MySQL could be to use [jails](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/jails.html) in that way you could just install the package like always beside inherit more security.

An easy way is to get an image with [ZFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS) + jails for this you could use [fabrik.red](https://github.com/fabrik-red/images/releases/tag/11.1), in any case, this are the basic steps to create a jail in your current system, you can find more here: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/jails-build.html

For this example the jail will be in `home/jail/mysql1`:

```
# mkdir -p /home/jail/mysql1
```

Fetch the base files and extract them into the jail:

```
# fetch ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/amd64/amd64/10.3-RELEASE/base.txz -o /tmp/base.txz
# tar -xvf /tmp/base.txz -C /home/jail/mysql1

# fetch ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/amd64/amd64/10.3-RELEASE/lib32.txz -o /tmp/lib32.txz
# tar -xvf /tmp/lib32.txz -C /home/jail/mysql1
```

Create `/etc/rc.conf/` and `/etc/resolv.conf`, on each jail home, the `/etc/rc.conf` can be something like:

```
cron_flags="$cron_flags -J 60"
sendmail_enable="NONE"
```

And for the `/etc/rc.conf` you could just copy the one you have in the main host:

```
# cp /etc/resolv.conf /home/jail/mysql1/resolv.conf
# cp /etc/resolv.conf /home/jail/mysql1/resolv.conf
```

Next create a `/etc/jail.conf`:

```
exec.start = "/bin/sh /etc/rc";
exec.stop = "/bin/sh /etc/rc.shutdown";
exec.clean;
mount.devfs;
allow.raw_sockets;
securelevel=3;
host.hostname="$name.your.tld";

mysql1 {
    ip4   = inherit;
    path  = "/home/jail/mysql1";
}

mysql2 {
    ip4   = inherit;
    path  = "/home/jail/mysql2";
}
```

Notice the `ip4 = inherit` it will make your jails use the same network on your host so that you don't have to do NAT or add unique IP's but because of this you will need to use a **different port** for each MySQL instance.

To start the jails do:

```
# /etc/rc.d/jail start
```

To check what jails are running type `jls` that will print something like:

```
JID  IP Address      Hostname                      Path
  1                  mysql1.your.tld              /home/jail/mysql1
  2                  mysql2.your.tld              /home/jail/mysql2
```

Enter to a jail by using `jexec`, for example, to access jail 1:

```
# jexec 1
```

Once in the jail, install your packages either by using [pkg](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/pkgng-intro.html) or ports.